# Interactivity with Shiny, rCharts and nvd3?

Tags: r, nvd3.js, shiny, rcharts

[EDITED]

I have been coding up a simple Shiny-based implementation of a multibar chart using the rcharts wrapper for nvd3. When I produce the graphic locally from the R console, I am able to interact with it and the transitions work as expected. However, when wrapped in the shiny interface, it does not redraw, nor does it allow for interactions with the plot itself.

I have pasted in the code that I am using below along with a sample data set. When run with the sample data, it works great. However, my actual data set is significantly larger (over 5k records in the trips dataset and over 100 entries in the stations dataset). Not sure why this would matter, but it seems to break the interface.

Here is the global.r file:

```
#global.r

preppedTrips <- read.csv("trips.csv")
stations <- read.csv("stations.csv")
stationnames <- as.character(stations$Name)
```

Here is the server.r file:

```
#ui.r 
require(rCharts)

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

  trips <- reactive({
    preppedTrips[preppedTrips$station == stationID(),]
  })

  stationID <- reactive({
    a <- as.character(stations[stations$Name == input$station,]$ID)
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    paste("Station ID is: ", stationID(), sep="")
  })

  output$plot <- renderChart({  
    n1 <- nPlot(value ~ time, group="group", data = trips(), type="multiBarChart")
    n1$set(dom = "plot")
    return(n1)
  })
})
```

Here is the ur.r file:

```
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("nvd3 test"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'station',
      label = "Stations",
      choices = stationnames,
      selected = 's1'),

    submitButton("Update View")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")), 

    showOutput("plot","nvd3")
  )
))
```

Here is a sample of the trips.csv file:

```
"","time","variable","value","group","station"
"8","07:00","V1",73,"Start","s1"
"9","08:00","V1",145,"Start","s1"
"10","09:00","V1",146,"Start","s1"
"11","10:00","V1",85,"Start","s1"
"12","11:00","V1",84,"Start","s1"
"13","12:00","V1",102,"Start","s1"
"14","13:00","V1",126,"Start","s1"
"32","07:00","V1",27,"End","s1"
"33","08:00","V1",97,"End","s1"
"34","09:00","V1",148,"End","s1"
"35","10:00","V1",70,"End","s1"
"36","11:00","V1",106,"End","s1"
"37","12:00","V1",84,"End","s1"
"38","13:00","V1",124,"End","s1"
"55","07:00","V1",24,"Start","s2"
"56","08:00","V1",107,"Start","s2"
"57","09:00","V1",127,"Start","s2"
"58","10:00","V1",54,"Start","s2"
"59","11:00","V1",50,"Start","s2"
"60","12:00","V1",59,"Start","s2"
"61","13:00","V1",45,"Start","s2"
"78","07:00","V1",34,"End","s2"
"79","08:00","V1",101,"End","s2"
"80","09:00","V1",95,"End","s2"
"81","10:00","V1",54,"End","s2"
"82","11:00","V1",44,"End","s2"
"83","12:00","V1",60,"End","s2"
"84","13:00","V1",56,"End","s2"
```

And here is a sample of the stations.csv file:

```
"","Name","ID"
"1","Station 1","s1"
"2","Station 2","s2"
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can inspect it. In the absence of code, it is impossible to say what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. The ui.r and server.r code has been added.

Comment: Can you also post a sample of your data files `trips.csv` and `stations.csv` so that your example is reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the original code for the default value of selected. Fixed now.

Comment: This works for me. Without your complete stations.csv and trips.csv file, I won't be able to debug your issue. If your data is confidential, you can sanitize it some way or email it to me so that I can take a closer look.

Comment: Ramnath, turns out that there was one row with odd data at the end of the csv file. I removed that and problem solved. Cleanliness is next to godliness...or something like that.

Comment: Hehe.. Glad that you were able to solve it. Can you post it as an answer, accept it and close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, egg on my face. Some bad data in the last row of the csv file broke the build.